# jQuery effect returning undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, highlight, effect

I have the following block:

```
$('.new_comment').live('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr){
  $('.comments article:last').after(xhr.responseText).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
})
```

So when the `new_comment` form is submitted it calls this.

The `after()` function works fine, but the `effect()` call is throwing this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('.comments article:last').after(xhr.responseText).effect("highlight", {}, 3000)')
```

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.16.

**UPDATE:** `xhr.responseText` returns a newly created `article` element, like this:

```
<article id="2">
  <h6><a href="#">Joe</a> <span>(<a href="#2">less than a minute ago</a>)</span></h6>
  <p>This is the new comment!</p>
</article>
```

After it's added, the `.comments` DOM looks like this:

```
<section class="comments">
  <h3>Comments</h3>
  <article id="1">
    <h6><a href="#">Joe</a> <span>(<a href="#1">less than a minute ago</a>)</span></h6>
    <p>This is a comment!</p>
  </article>
  <article id="2">
    <h6><a href="#">Joe</a> <span>(<a href="#2">less than a minute ago</a>)</span></h6>
    <p>This is the new comment!</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

Also, if I run `console.log($('.comments article:last'));`, it definitely returns the object that was created.

Comment: What is the value of xhr.responseText that is returned by your server-side script?

Comment: For debugging purposes, what happens if you break that up into two statements like this:   $('.comments article:last').after(xhr.responseText);  $('.comments article:last').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);

Comment: @Joris: `xhr.responseText` returns a newly created `article` element

Comment: @MichaelRighi The same error happens.

Comment: @Shpigford Can you show us what the generated DOM looks like after the call to .after()?

Comment: @Shpigford, does your browser support the `<article>` element? Do you receive the same error if you write `$(xhr.responseText).insertAfter(".comments article:last").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);` (assuming you want to highlight the new item and not its previous sibling)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Yes, my browser supports it (latest version of Safari). And I still receive the same error using your sample code.

Comment: @Shpigford, okay, so I'm forced to ask this: when you [configured](http://jqueryui.com/download) your jQuery UI download, you *did* check the `Effect "Highlight"` check box, right? :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I'm just using the UI library hosted by Google: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you load jquery before jquery ui? Does $('section').effect("highlight", {}, 3000); throw the same error?

Comment: @agieche Yes, jquery is loaded before jquery ui. And your example code does indeed throw the same error.

Comment: Are you using prototype-framework, too?

Comment: Just figured out the problem. I was loading the jQuery library twice. Once using the pre-bundled version with Rails and once from Google's CDN. Removed one of them and now all works fine. Sigh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was loading the jQuery library twice. Once using the pre-bundled version with Rails and once from Google's CDN. Removed one of them and now all works fine. Sigh.

Answer (score -1):

New element created due ajax post is not chained with parent container. It seems like new namespace is created by posting. So you can't touch any element of page body which is not defined in result part of post function.